# Class not found PHP Nova Pochta

Tags: php, class

I have 2 files:

1:

```
include_once 'Core/autoload.php';

if (!defined('NOVA_POSHTA_PATH_SDK')) {
    define('NOVA_POSHTA_PATH_SDK', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

    \NovaPoshta\Core\Autoload::init();
}
```

autoload:

```
namespace NovaPoshta\Core\;

class Autoload
{
    public static function init()
    {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }

        return spl_autoload_register(array('\NovaPoshta\Core\Autoload', 'load'));
    }

    public static function load($className)
    {
        $className = str_replace('NovaPoshta\\', '', $className);
        $className = NOVA_POSHTA_PATH_SDK . $className . '.php';
        $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);

        if ((file_exists($className) === false) || (is_readable($className) === false)) {
            return false;
        }

        require($className);

        return true;
    }
}
```

If executing first code i recive this error:
Class 'NovaPoshta\Core\Autoload' not found
Help me pls. What can be is? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the file is where you expect it to be and the correct one is loaded? You should receive a syntax error as `namespace NovaPoshta\Core\;` is not valid.

Comment: You only include the file, you don't require it. That means it must not have been read. Which makes sense, as in your other question you report it has parse errors. It must not even have been properly named in the include directive as otherwise the fatal parse error would haven taken precedence over the class not found error.